# Store instances of class to delete at will

Tags: python

For my pygame-script I made a dictionary to store references to class instances in, so I could add and remove objects from the game loop by adding or removing them form the dictionary, because the in the game loop, I would iterate over that dict and run every instance in there.
That's the theory at least. In practice I get "line 89, in startup

```
key.run()
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'run'"

I didn't surprise me to get that error. But I was wondering, how would I **actually** be able to only run the instance of the class if is is inside the dict monitoring the active instances?

```
def startup(self):
        pygame.init()
        ...
        # Read out the entity definitions from the file, where they are stored.
        entFile = open("inits/initObjs.txt","r")

        # Write each line, (which corresponds to one entity be design of the file) into a list "entities"
        entities = list()
        for line in entFile:
            entities.append(line)

        # create a name for every instance of an object defined in the file
        for i in range(len(entities)):
            ID = "entity_%d" %(i)
            # Add ID and entity definition to self.entDict
            self.entDict[ID] = repr(entities[i])
            # Now initiate the object instance (entity_<ID> = <instance definition>)
            exec("entity_%d = %s" % (i, repr(entities[i])))

        while True:
            # Get every active instance (every instance in the dict is.).
            # The ID is the name of the instance, like unit1 = Unit(arg1,arg2...).
            # run() is a method of the class. Now run it.
            # Instaces will be taken out of the game loop be deletion of their ID in self.entDict
            for key, value in self.entDict.iteritems():
                key.run()
            ...
```

This is what a single line in initObjs.txt looks like:

```
Button(ID,"data/sprites/buttons/launch_off.png","data/sprites/buttons/launch_on.png",0.01*self.width,0.01*self.height,90,26,0,game1,False,True)
```

Comment: No, the key is the name of the instance. I want to know how I can actually execute that instance by looking up it's "name" in the dict of instances to be executed.

Comment: If I knew all that I might not even have had to ask my question. I googled a lot how to deal with this stuff and understood the least.

But how **would** I simply store the instance in the dict?

Comment: Yes, but how? I am only pulling the definitions from the external TXT file. I am not even creating the instances yet. That is my very question! How can I create the instances from loading a mere string from the external file?

Comment: That answer doesn't help me.

Comment: Which is neither my fault nor my problem. I don't know what's in the file, where it came from, whether you have any choice or input into the format used, what your reasons for storage in the file are, ... How, then, can I give an answer (or even advice)?

Comment: I did post what is in the file right in my start post. It's full of lines like that.

Comment: My reason for storage is that in the end I want to be able to create the instances by the press of a button. And for that I want them to be predefined and stored in an external file. The rest of you post I don't understand.

Comment: Long and the short of it is this almost certainly isn't the best way to do it. `pickle` may help, or develop your own XML/CSV/whatever format of you need it to be human-readable, or consider a database of some kind if there will be many objects. `exec` (and `eval`) is generally a sign you've taken a wrong turn somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store it might be to serialize it first rather than trying to execute it from a command string.

Have a look at the pickle module: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html

Comment: hmm, that'd be an idea. But wouldn't that eat up a lot of resources to constantly dump and load objects from external files?

Comment: why would you constantly dump and load? dump once when you create and initialize the object, and load on startup.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to like my solution. But it is sufficient for my purposes.

```
def startup(self):
        pygame.init()
        ...

        # Read out the entity definitions from the file, where tehy are stored.
        entFile = open("inits/initObjs.txt","r")

        # Write each line, (which corresponds to one entity be design of the file) into a list "entities"
        entities = list()
        for line in entFile:
            entities.append(line)

        # create a name for every instance of an object defined in the file
        for i in range(len(entities)):
            ID = "entity_%d" %(i)
            # Add ID and entity definition to self.entDict
            self.entDict[ID] = entities[i]
            # Now initiate the object instance (entity_<ID> = <instance definition>)
            exec("entity_%d = %s" % (i, entities[i]))

            screen.blit(background, backgroundRect)
            # Get every active instance (every instance in the dict is.).
            # The ID is the name of the instance, like unit1 = Unit(arg1,arg2...).
            # run() is a method of the class. Now run it.
            # Instaces will be taken out of the game loop be deletion of their ID in self.entDict

            for key, value in self.entDict.iteritems():
                key = eval(key)
                key.run()
        ...
```